# NSDictionary to NSArray containing keys and values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I don't know if there is an easy way to implement this, or I need to implemente the algorithm by myself.

This is what I have (NSDictionary):

```
 {
    14 =         (
        "M"
    );
    15 =         (
        "H"
    );
    16 =         (
        "F",
        "G"
    );
```

And this is what I want (NSArray):

```
     {
        14,
        "M",
        15,
        "H"
...
}
```

Im looking for an easy way, in case I need to do the algorithm I'll do by myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over the `NSDictionary`and add the keys and values like this:

```
  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [may enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
    {
        [array addObject:key];

        for (int i = 0; i < [obj count]; i++){
            [array addObject:[obj objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: I made it work, and its not exactly what I m looking for, thanks anyway

Comment: @AntonioMG, I think you need to order keys and values before iterating since dictionary is unordered

Comment: Hi, I modified your response to make it work! thanks so much, that was brilliant and fast!

Comment: You can eliminate that inner look by replacing it with `[array addObjectsFromArray:obj];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
NSMutableArray *allObjs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[d allKeys ]];
[allObjs addObjectsFromArray:[d allValues]];
```

Comment: is that going to respect the order of the keys, values? I have the feeling that is going to be an array of keys followed by an array of values

Comment: No, the only order will be - keys, then values

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order.  Other answer will keep keys and values associated, but any 2 calls might generate a differently ordered result.